# TwitterFeed: Reddit RSS Feed with Links to URL instead of comments section

Tags: twitter, rss, reddit

I created a Yahoo Pipes feed that takes the top posts from a subreddit and changes the URL to the actual website URL rather than the comments section of the site.

This PIPE can be found here:  http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=5ab75d6316349a48aa790fb41f4e80de

I'm trying to use TwitterFeed to automate the submission of the top posts to my twitter account.  However, when I submit the RSS version of this pipe to TwitterFeed (http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=5ab75d6316349a48aa790fb41f4e80de&_render=rss), I get the following error: "Your feed might be empty or missing publish dates or GUIDs. A feed needs to contain publish dates or GUIDs in order to work with twitterfeed."

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I checked the feed and it does have both `<guid>` and `<pubDate>` elements... which makes me think that Twitterfeed is not able to get the content from the pipe's RSS feed.

I know [from practice](http://superfeedr.com/) that Yahoo Pipes is quite aggressive and tends to block services who poll them too often. It's quite likely that Twitterfeed has a lot of Yahoo Pipes feeds and they may be blocked, but only someone from Twitterfeed and/or Yahoo Pipes will be able to confirm that.